# Is there identity whitelisted firewall available in cloud platforms (vs plain old static IP whitelisting)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, authentication, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Before Amazon acquired Cloud 9 I had been using the service for few years.

Having been Cloud Native developer since 2015 I really loved it, because they really pushed the ideas, how Cloud Native software development could work, like sharing work spaces with links (good for mentoring junior developers remotely) etc.

The great thing about Cloud 9 was, that I could make a public HTTP server from my workspace, but at the same time, the end-point was only accessible for Cloud 9 authenticated users for whom I had given access rights. So it kind of combined firewall and IAM.

In AWS and GCP there seems to be only firewall option, which allows me to make things public or private and accessible from static IP addresses. Configuring static IP address would be very cumbersome. Instead of static IP restricted address I would like to provide access to `authenticated_user:myself`.

Having been Cloud 9 user for ages, I got accustomed to these semi-safe sandbox development methods, where I use private server behind OAuth2-style ACL to make it public for some users (if someone had cracked my Cloud 9 credentials I would had been screwed anyway). Is there a way to make this happen in GCP or AWS?

I am looking for cloud service native features, which do not require coding it myself.

Comment: Why `azure` tag?

Comment: Remote Cloud 9 workstation could also be hosted at Azure